# CSS fill horizontal menu bar with colour

Tags: html, css, colors, menubar

I'm creating a horizontal menu bar using a list, however I'm struggling to fill it will colour. I'd like the bar to fill with colour to the right of "links". However, just setting the background colour of the entire list doesn't work, as it also sets a background colour for an area that I'd like to keep transparent. Code and screenshots are below, thanks in advance!

Html code seems to not be working in preview, here's a pastebin link in case it's actually broken: https://pastebin.com/TxQV50Ey

Screenshot: [image: Website menu bar]

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../resources/background.png");
  font-family: "courier";
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="../resources/logo.png" alt="MClogo" width=50px height=50px style="margin-left: 5px;"></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_IGNORE.png" width=15px height=50px></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_imageboard.png" width=150px height=50px></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_downloads.png" width=123px height=50px></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_tools.png" width=123px height=50px></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_links.png" width=123px height=50px></li>
  <!--
    -->
  <li><img src="../resources/bt_PADDING.png" width=50px height=50px style="float: right; background-color: #BBBFDC;"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you seem to be using `../resources/` files which are files relative to the file system you're on.

Comment: Thats not really a problem at the moment since the website isn't up yet

Comment: You can make another `li` and then set it's width, and set the background color

Comment: Surely that would go underneath the current list?

Comment: Take a look --> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOYYKo

Comment: If you expect the entire bar to be colored, you need to apply `background` related properties to the `<ul>`, not to the buttons (`<li>`s).

Comment: You will also want to add this `overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;` to the containing parent `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add background color or background-image to `ul` Element that is the parent element so it fills the entire background